# Getting segfault due to string data type variable in PROTOBUF server and client communication through sockets on recv end in cpp

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, protocol-buffers

When I am sending a protobuf variable through socket communication on recv end I am trying to display the string variable of protobuf I got segmentation in this remaining Data type other than String they are working fine but string variable case I got segmentation How can I over come in Protobuf string datatype segmentation fault other than we have any other data type for store the string data type.

I create a example.proto with in string variable name is there
I am compile example.proto with protoc compiler (`protoc example.proto --cpp_out <path>`) 
it create two files two files example.pb.h, example.pb.cc 
By using these files I create a test_server.cpp  and test_client.cpp 
And  compile it. but at the time of both programms runing I sent a protobuf variable on recv side it give segmentation fault due to trying to display string variable.

**How can I solve this problem?**

**example.proto**

```
package data;
message  star
{ optional string name=1; }
```

**server.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include"example.pb.h"
#include"example.pb.cc"

int main() 
{ 
    int sd,csd;
    sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    perror("socket");
    sockaddr_in ser,cli;
    ser.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ser.sin_port=htons(7878);
    ser.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("X.Y.Z.A");
    bzero(ser.sin_zero, 8);
    size_t s=16;

    if(bind(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&ser, s)==-1)
        cout<<"Bind FAIL\n";
    else
        cout<<"Bind Success\n";

    if((csd=accept(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&cli, &s))==-1)
        cout<<"Connection Accept FAIL\n";
    else
        cout<<"ConnectioN Accept Success\n";

    star pkt;
    recv(csd,&pkt,sizeof(pkt),0);
    cout<<"\t String Name: "<<pkt.name<<endl; //Here only i get segmentation
    close(sd);
    close(csd);
}
```

---

**client.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<strings.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include"example.pb.h"
#include"example.pb.cc"

int main()
{
    int sd;
    sd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
    perror("socket");
    sockaddr_in ser;
    ser.sin_family=AF_INET;
    ser.sin_port=htons(7878);
    ser.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("X.Y.Z.A");
    bzero(ser.sin_zero, 8);

    if(connect(sd,(struct sockaddr *)&ser, 16)==-1)
        cout<<"connect FAIL\n";
    else
        cout<<"connect Success\n";

    star pkt;
    pkt.set_name("Pratap");
    cout<<"Send Data without help of another variable....\n";
    send(sd,&pkt,sizeof(pkt) ,MSG_CONFIRM);
    close(sd);
}
```

---

Comment: please any body can give me a solution for this...

Comment: We need a small, compilable code example to be able to help. Since it's seg faulting, showing where the seg fault is will also help.

Comment: i add my server and client programms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
star pkt;
recv(csd,&pkt,sizeof(pkt),0);
```

and here:

```
star pkt;
pkt.set_name("Pratap");
cout<<"Send Data without help of another variable....\n";
send(sd,&pkt,sizeof(pkt) ,MSG_CONFIRM);
```

You can't receive/send the `star` instance directly without de/serializing it from/to protobuf wire format first. Have a look at the `ParseFrom` `SerializeTo` methods of the [`protobuf::MessageLite`](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#MessageLite) class.

The best way is to send the length of the serialized message first in a fixed format (e.g. a `uint32_t` in network byte order). Then the receiver can read this first and allocate a buffer of the appropriate size before receiving the serialized message that is send afterwards.

**UPDATE:**
Try s.th. like this:

**Sender.cpp**

```
star pbMsgObj;
pbMsgObj.set_name("Pratap");

std::string pkt;
pbMsgObj.SerializeToString(&pkt); // Serialize the message object to 
                                  // protobuf wire format.
uint32_t msgLength = pkt.size();
uint32_t sndMsgLength = htonl(msg_length); // Ensure network byte order

send(sd,&sndMsgLength ,sizeof(uint32_t) ,MSG_CONFIRM); // Send the message length
send(sd,pkt.c_str() ,msgLength ,MSG_CONFIRM); // Send the message data
```

**Receiver.cpp**

```
star msgObject;
uint32_t msgLength;
recv(csd,&msgLength,sizeof(uint32_t),0); // Receive the message length
msgLength = ntohl(msgLength); // Ensure host system byte order

std::vector<uint8_t> pkt; // Allocate a receive buffer
pkt.resize(msgLength,0x00);

recv(csd,&(pkt[0]),msgLength,0); // Receive the message data
std::string tmp;
tmp.assign(&(pkt[0]),pkt.size()); // Convert message data to a string

msgObject.ParseFromString(tmp); // Deserialize the message object from
                                // protobuf wire format.
```

**NOTE:**
De-/Serializing from/to a unique, efficient wire format used with various language bindings is the whole point of google protocol buffers.

For twiddling out the bits of possible sender/receiver patterns, instead of creating 'raw' sockets you might find [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) being a useful framework. Anyway listen to good advice(!): Keep message (payload) format and send/recv behavior as separate as possible.

Comment: The concept is pretty simple, isn't it? Anything else you need can be found in the [google protobuf documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) IMHO. Do you have further particular questions? If it's working I'd appreciate you simply accept the answer.

Comment: @Jagadheesh Another point: I think it's been working with fixed types by accidence. The data layout of the generated protobuf classes using only int and bool types might have matched with what you were sending and receiving. But it's not intended to be used in this way.

Comment: @Jagadheesh Lost interest? Confused?

Comment: hi g-makulik sir, i am workig on that if any doubt i will ask You...        Now it is working fine with string and bytes data type..