# Sending and recv array content through socket in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets

I am taking some data into array and sending it to receiver.  Problem is array size I will get is not predefined.

for temporary purpose I declared `int ar[10]` so it works without error. But this is not correct way I think. How can I allocate it's size dynamically here?

At sender side:

```
for (std::map < int, std::vector < std::string > >::iterator hit = three_highest.begin(); hit != three_highest.end(); ++hit) {
for (std::vector < std::string >::iterator vit = (*hit).second.begin(); vit != (*hit).second.end(); vit++) {
        ar[i]= hit-> first;
        i++;
    }
    }

    if ((bytecount = send(*csock, (char *)ar, i *sizeof(int), 0)) == -1) { // Here we cant send lenth-1. It consider exact
            }
```

At rec end:

```
if((bytecount = recv(hsock, ar, sizeof(ar), 0))== -1){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
        goto FINISH;
    }
     x= sizeof(ar)/sizeof(int);
    printf("x is %d: \n ",x);
    for(i=0; i < (sizeof(ar)/sizeof(*ar));i++)
    {
        std::cout << ar[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

How ever I could not send and recv properly. Your help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the variable `hit`? What is the declaration of `ar` (on both sides)?

Comment: you first send the size of the array, then the actual array. The receiver first reads the size, resizes the vector, then reads size*sizeof(int) straight into vector.data()

Comment: Oh, and why are you using `hit` when assigning to the array when it's `vit` you're iterating with? It just means that all entries in `ar` (whatever that is) will be the same.

Comment: @stijn You should put that as an answer.

Comment: Well you say it works for fixed array size right. Then to declare dynamic array you could just use: `int * ar = new int[arraySize];` now `ar` is an array of type `int` with `arraySize` number of elements. Then to make it work you would probably have to send the length of the array over the network too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Sorry. I have edited the code!

Comment: @stijn: Thanks. But I am failing to do it. Can you please help me out to give complete example. I would be grateful!

Comment: I've given a sample for a similar problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463414/i-getting-segment-fault-due-to-string-data-type-variable-in-protobuf-server-and/18464632#18464632). Ignore the protobuf stuff, basically it's sending and receiving dynamically sized arrays as you want it.

Comment: @g-makulik: For int array I could not figure out how to do!

Comment: For `int` arrays it would be similar using just `std::vector<int>`. But I'd recommend conversion from/to wireformat of the integers using `ntohl()`,`htonl()` as done for the array size prefix sent.

Comment: @g-makulik: I think using `vector` will remove the need of dynamic memory allocation, right? As stijn did send and recv, similar this can be done for string too, right? Or multiple send() would be received by frist recv() till 512Bytes ?

Comment: @Catty Unfortunately no! `std::vector` does dynamic memory allocation under the hood. But you can do the same for `std::string` managed buffers, yes. Don't get what you mean about _'1st `recv()` till 512Bytes'_

Answer (score 4):

The principle for sending variable length data over a socket (or pretty much any other communication device out there) is always the same: first send the size of the data so the receiver knows what comes next, then send the actual data. In this case you want to send an array of integers and since this is C++ I'll give a pseudo-code example using vector< int > (although it should work for any POD type and any type os socket/port/...):

```
//this is of utter importance: sender and receiver must use the same types
typedef std::int64_t size_type;

void Send( const std::vector< int >& vec, socket sock )
{
  const size_type sz = vec.size();
  send( sock, &sz, sizeof( sz ) );
  send( sock, &(*vec.first()), sz * sizeof( int ) );
}

void Recv( std::vector< int >& vec, socket soc )
{
  size_type sz;
  recv( sock, &sz, sizeof( sz ) );
  vec.resize( sz );
  recv( sock, &(*vec.first()), sz * sizeof( int ) );
}

//make an array containing 3 elements
std::vector< int > ar;
ar.push_back( 0 );
ar.push_back( 1 );
ar.push_back( 2 );
Send( ar, socket );

//the other end
std::vector< int > ar;
Recv( ar, sock );
//now ar contains 0,1,2
```

Important: I omitted casting from size_type to int (which is normally what send/recv) take, but if your data becomes large it is important to handle this correctly by splitting the send over multiple calls. Likewise for the receiving end. Also, as you can see, I omitted all error checking. Don't do that in actual code.

Comment: thanks a lot. But I am still facing problem with array declaraation and sending for my program! It would have been gread if you have written above for my case!

Comment: It's not 'always the same'.  You can use a protocol with delimiters, escaped if necessary, if the length of the data is not known at the time of the first send.

Comment: This solution is 'difficult to use' if the receiver/s are of unknown endianness.

Comment: I'd recommend converting the raw integers to wire format if they're going over sockets.

Comment: @MartinJames very true, but I'm just showing the principle here. There are enough libraries out there that implement it properly.

Comment: This code cannot work in general. It ignores the count returned by recv(), which is *not* guaranteed to fill the buffer passed to it. In general if you want to read *x* bytes you have to loop.

Comment: @EJP I know. And that's not the only reason it wont' work. But again, just showing the principle.

Comment: If you're going to post actual code it should work. Your statement that 'it is important to handle this correctly by splitting the send over a number of calls' is also incorrect. It isn't. -1

Comment: @EJP I called it 'pseudo-code example' :P Also if send takes an int, you're going to have to do _something_ if sz * sizeof( int ) > 2^31, right?

Comment: @stijn: You coded significant code. Can you please give actual code. Little more effort. And why you send twice `send( sock, &sz, sizeof( sz ) );
  send( sock, &(*vec.first()), sz * sizeof( int ) );` Only one is not engouh? same for recv too!

Comment: @Catty No one send is not enough. the whole point is sending the size, then the data. If you do not send the size first the receiving end does not know how much data to receive. And no I can't post our production code here, it's not OSS. Check the link in g-makulik's comment above, it' pretty complete.