# Sending and receiving std::string over socket

Tags: c++, string, sockets, c++11

I have seen similar question on SO but non answers my question.
Here I am trying to send and recv string:

I am sending std::string :

```
if( (bytecount=send(hsock, input_string.c_str(), input_string.length(),0))== -1)
```

Can it be correctly received by this?

```
if ((bytecount = recv(*csock, rcv.c_str(), rcv.length(), 0)) == -1)
```

I am getting error:

> error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]` on recv line!

Comment: I've made up an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463414/i-getting-segment-fault-due-to-string-data-type-variable-in-protobuf-server-and/18464632#18464632) that might help you. It demonstrates sending arbitrary length string data by sending the actual length up front (just ignore the protobuf stuff).

Comment: @g-makulik: thanks alot! what is `star pkt;` will it work for std::string? If you can write piece of code I wouuld greatful.  Other wise I will try myself.

Comment: `star pkt;` is an object instance of a protobuf generated class. It can be de-/serialized from/to `std::string` objects. These are used to send/recv over the socket and what should demonstrate your needs.

Comment: I didn't had time earlier today to adapt the answer for your case. Have a look please.

Answer (score 21):

No it can't.  [c_str()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns a `const char*`.  This means you cannot overwrite the contents of the pointer.

If you want to receive the data, you must create a buffer, e.g. with a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and then use that to create a `std::string`.

```
// create the buffer with space for the data
const unsigned int MAX_BUF_LENGTH = 4096;
std::vector<char> buffer(MAX_BUF_LENGTH);
std::string rcv;   
int bytesReceived = 0;
do {
    bytesReceived = recv(*csock, &buffer[0], buffer.size(), 0);
    // append string from buffer.
    if ( bytesReceived == -1 ) { 
        // error 
    } else {
        rcv.append( buffer.cbegin(), buffer.cend() );
    }
} while ( bytesReceived == MAX_BUF_LENGTH );
// At this point we have the available data (which may not be a complete
// application level message).
```

The above code will receive 4096 bytes at a time.  If there is more than 4K sent, it will keep looping and append the data to `recv` until there is no more data.

Also note the use of `&buffer[0]` instead of `buffer.data()`. Taking the address of the first element is the way to access the non-const pointer and avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: thanks, what is `length` in `std::vector<char> buffer(length)` as I dont know what exactly the length of receiving data is?

Comment: You must decide the maximum amount of data you want to receive and define that as length.  There is no way for you to know the amount of data that you will actually receive.  If you receive less than your max buffer size you have the whole message, otherwise you need to call receive again as there is more data on the line.

Comment: I am dealing with big data comming from web pages. I suspect what should I use it! any other way?

Comment: I want solution which does not limit for buffer limited buffer size!

Comment: @Catty to receive more data, you must loop and call `recv` again.  Updated answer.

Comment: thanks a lot. I think this will solve my issue. Let me check for my application!

Comment: should it be `bytesReceived = recv(*csock, buffer.data(), buffer.length() -1 , 0));` ?

Comment: *// At this point we have all the data.* - What does "all the data" mean exactly? (It's too easy for someone to erroneously think you mean an entire application-level message, which of course would be totally incorrect.)

Comment: For less then `MAX_BUF_LENGTH` sent your reader will block until the other end closes the connection.

Answer (score 17):

The best way is to send the length of the string data first in a fixed format (e.g. a `uint32_t` in network byte order). Then the receiver can read this first and allocate a buffer of the appropriate size before receiving the serialized message that is send afterwards.

`sd` and `csd` are assumed to be already present socket descriptors.

**Sender.cpp**

```
std::string dataToSend = "Hello World! This is a string of any length ...";

uint32_t dataLength = htonl(dataToSend.size()); // Ensure network byte order 
                                                // when sending the data length

send(sd,&dataLength ,sizeof(uint32_t) ,MSG_CONFIRM); // Send the data length
send(sd,dataToSend.c_str(),dataToSend.size(),MSG_CONFIRM); // Send the string 
                                                           // data
```

**Receiver.cpp**

```
uint32_t dataLength;
recv(csd,&rcvDataLength,sizeof(uint32_t),0); // Receive the message length
dataLength = ntohl(dataLength ); // Ensure host system byte order

std::vector<uint8_t> rcvBuf;    // Allocate a receive buffer
rcvBuf.resize(dataLength,0x00); // with the necessary size

recv(csd,&(rcvBuf[0]),dataLength,0); // Receive the string data

std::string receivedString;                        // assign buffered data to a 
receivedString.assign(&(rcvBuf[0]),rcvBuf.size()); // string
```

Advantage is. you don't have to mess around with multiple buffered reads and copying to the received string. Additionally you'll know at the receiver side when the sent data is finally complete.

Disadvantage is, you're introducing kind of a 'protocol' when sending the length first.

Comment: *＋1* for using `&rcvBuf[0]`.

Answer (score 6):

No, [`std::string::c_str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) returns `const char*` which is means it's read only. You could allocate a local buffer and create string object from local buffer after `recv` returns successfully.

You need to tell `recv` function to read a specific length of data, for example you want to read 512 bytes each time:

```
#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];

recv(*csock, recvbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN, 0);
```

Comment: thanks, but what could be the size of local buffer? do we need to give it? because I dont know what would be the size of receiving value!

Comment: I want solution which does not limit for buffer limited buffer size!

Comment: @Catty You need to design and implement a protocol (or use an existing protocol). Otherwise, how will the receiver know how many bytes to receive?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes, I was trying to implement protocol for my purpose. But I think Steve answer will dill with any size of data!

Comment: @Catty, Steve's answer sets length 4096, it doesn't deal with any size.

Comment: @billz: But i believe it will work for any possible size, if I am not wrong!

Comment: @Catty It will get you some data, but then you have to implement the actual protocol to decide whether that data constitutes an entire "message" or not. You can't avoid implementing a protocol.

Answer (score 0):

> `error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’ [-fpermissive]` on recv line!

Dialing into this particular question, you wrote (*sans* the `if` statement):

```
bytecount = recv(*csock, rcv.c_str(), rcv.length(), 0)
```

`rcv.c_str()` retrieves a `const char*` pointer. The `const char*` was coerced to the `const void*`. The only way I know to get non-const pointer and avoid undefined behavior is taking the address of the first element in a `std::string` or `std::vector`:

```
bytecount = recv(*csock, &rcv[0], rcv.length(), 0)
```

Getting the non-const pointer like that is only valid for STL containers that provide contiguous memory. The trick would not work for a `map`, `multimap` or other associative containers.

@πάντα-ῥεῖ is the only answer that picked up on it, but he did not stress the point.