# Unix TCP socket send() doesn't correctly download any other files other than HTML files?

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, tcp

I am attempting to create a simple HTTP proxy that takes an HTTP GET request from a client (using wget on Unix). The problem I originally had was that I didn't realize send() or read()/recv() doesn't necessarily transfer all data at the socket after 1 call. To remedy this I looped the read() call and added the return values of read() together until it returned 0 (meaning there is no more data to read).

In doing this I get the size of the file to send back to the client via the send() call, but so far it only works with html files. I don't loop the send() call because the return value of the call is always equal to the length argument passed in; meaning that it sends all the data in my buffer back to the client.

The client (via wget) claims to have downloaded 100% of the file but when I download the file via wget without using my http proxy and run the diff command on the resulting file, it always says the binary files differ (tried pdfs, pngs, jpegs etc...) unless it is an html file.

I really don't understand why this is the case. Below is a snippet of my recv() / read() loop and the send() portion.

```
   ...//Reading from website (the HTTP GET response)
    char responsebuf[BUFFER_SIZE];
    bzero(responsebuf,BUFFER_SIZE);
    int readval = recv(newsock,responsebuf,BUFFER_SIZE,MSG_PEEK);
    cout<<"Peeking at response from website via proxy =)"<<endl;
    printf("Peeked Message is....\n\n%s\n\n", responsebuf);
    string temp(responsebuf);
    int contentlen = parseResponseLength(temp);
    cout<<"Content len from peek message is "<<contentlen<<endl; //Works
    int cumlative = 0;
    string whole_response;
    char responsebuf2[BUFFER_SIZE];
    while(1){
     ssize_t readval = recv(newsock,responsebuf2,BUFFER_SIZE,0);
     string chunk(responsebuf2);
     whole_response+=chunk;
     cout<<"Read val currently is "<<readval<<endl;
     cumlative+=readval;
     cout<<"Cumulative read val is "<<cumlative<<endl;
     if(readval==0){
      break;
     }
   }



... //Sending back to client
     char finalbuf[cumlative];
     bzero(finalbuf,cumlative);
     strncpy(finalbuf,whole_response.c_str(),cumlative);
     int sent_back = send(clients.at(i), finalbuf, cumlative, 0);
     cout<<"Number of bytes sent back to client "<<sent_back<<endl;
```

Comment: If you're reading a chunk of data that should be 1000 bytes, you need to read 1000 bytes.

Comment: A return value of 0 should indicate you've received everything the client has to send (assuming *they* are the one that shut down the socket).  But the **should** part is unfortunately usually a very practical consideration with socket code.

Comment: Recommended reading:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18670807/sending-and-receiving-stdstring-over-socket

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I see the problem I store the HTTP response in a string and attempt to send it with string.c_str(). The problem with this is that it doesn't work for binary data so any other file type other than text (html, txt files) wouldn't work. Instead I sent with the .data() function. And loop just in case all data in not sent on the first call

New Send snippet below

```
 //Assuming HTTP get response is in string whole_response  
  char* finalbuf = new char[fullLen];                             
  memcpy(finalbuf,whole_response.data(),fullLen);
  //length is fullLen named var
  int returned = -1;
  int bytesSent = 0;
  int bytesRemaining = fullLen;
  while(bytesSent < fullLen){
    returned = send(clients.at(i),finalbuf+bytesSent , bytesRemaining , 0);
    if(returned == -1){
        perror("Send() data back to client failed: ");
        exit(1);
    }
    bytesSent+= returned;
    bytesRemaining -= returned;
  }
```