# Send string on socket in cpp

Tags: c++

I and sending a msg inside class using sockets like

```
class Msg{
    int msgId;
    string msgstr; // know about the largest msg (say=> "abcd")
}
```

now the other side is not receiving the `msgstr` but the `msgId` is being received.

What should I put in `size_t len` parameter of `send()` func.

`sizeof(Msg)` returns `40`; so should I put `40`;
or since max `msgstr` is "abcd" so should I put `4(int) + 4(msgstr.size()) = 8`

I have tried both these method other side not receiving the `msgstr`

```
Msg msg1;
send(sockfd, &msg1, ____, 0)
```

Comment: You cannot send a `string` over a socket. A `string` is a often a pointer to data stored elsewhere and all you'll wind up transmitting is the address on your computer of the `string`'s data in your process's memory space. That's not so useful to another computer or another process. Even inside the same process, you'll wind up with two `string`s pointing to the same place and that always ends in disaster.

Comment: How to achieve this kind of functionality?

Comment: @lupin Send the *data* that the string represents, not the object.  That is called *object serialization*.  You would have the same issue if you tried to write the std::string to a file in the same fashion -- a file with junk data.

Comment: You'll have to send `msgId` and `msgstr` separately. You can `send(sockfd, msg1.msgstr.c_str(),msg1.msgstr.length(), 0)` to send the string data, but if you're using TCP/IP you should add on some extra information to specify the length of the `string` or include the null terminator so the receiver can tell the messages apart. TCP/IP mashes everything together into a single stream and the receiver never really knows how much they'll get of the message at a time.

Comment: @lupin You might be interested in google protobuf.

Comment: Ha! That comment will make this one look a little funny! [Here's a link to an answer to another question that does most of what you want.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18678024/4581301)

Comment: Don't use `struct`s or `class`es as network protocols. There are nearly a dozen things wrong with the practice. Use network protocols as network protocols.

Comment: @user207421 since I know the max length of string i.e. 4bytes. I can replace the string with char data[4].

Comment: @lupin You might run into problems with alignement and padding.

Comment: A side note: since `int` is not always the same size ([2 bytes, `sizeof(long)`]), you have to be careful here too. Prefer the fixed width integers in `<cstdint>` so that you get a predictable size (or a compiler error if the size can't be guaranteed).